# Disable Stereo on Windows Vista (without hardware changes)

Tags: windows, windows-vista, audio, stereo

I have a PC that only has one speaker working (big speaker, attached to a 27 inch TV/monitor). I listen to music and some songs are all messed up unless they have both speakers working. Since I only have the left speaker working, I want to have both sides play on the left.

Is that possible (without changing hardware)?

Comment: i do not have a Vista machine to test on, but where you select your speaker setup isn't there a Monaural (Mono, Single Speaker etc) option?

Answer (score 1):

On the volume icon in the taskbar tray, right-click, click `Playback devices`, right-click on your device, click `Properties`, then go to the `Levels` tab, then to the right of the first slider, click `Balance`, and you should be able to configure different sliders, like so:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this does not move the right side to the left. It only reduces the volume of the right side (which does not work anyway). (I have only L and R sliders in the Balance popup)

Comment: Sorry to hear that @GeorgeBailey...Good to know for future reference, I learned something today...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to (studiohack's answer should cover you), but a simple/cheap hardware fix would be to use a [y-splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z5CP) in reverse.

Comment: Well, first, that won't work. The sound he wants is not coming out of the right channel in the first place, so mixing the L and R together won't help.

Comment: Second: Sorry, but "using a Y-splitter in reverse" is a very bad thing. The outputs are low impedance, intended to source minimal current into high-impedance loads. Connect them together and each sees a very low impedance load. Result: very low levels to the driven input and maybe even damage to the outputs due to excessive current. Please see "Why Not Wye", http://www.rane.com/note109.html . That's a pro audio site but the situation with PC outputs is if anything worse, as they are designed to drive headphones and so are of lower impedance than typical pro audio outputs.